# Getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined Error on specific pages only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I've been using iziModal and I'm getting an error on specific pages that's related to iziModal. The full error code is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>       at r.fn.init.t.fn.(anonymous function) [as iziModal] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.0/js/iziModal.min.js:6:22531)
>       at http://localhost:8000/js/scripts.js:3:17

scripts.js:3:17 on that error points to:

```
$('#userPanel').iziModal({
  title: 'View User Data',
  subtitle: 'View and update each employee\'s records in the database',
  icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-user',
  padding: '15',
  fullscreen: true
});
```

It's causing my ajax and jquery scripts on the affected pages to not work. My script order is right as well.

Comment: Does a `#userPanel` element exist on those pages …?

Comment: @CBroe That's kind of the thing. It isn't. It's only available on the page where the script is working.

Comment: @Nar that sounds like a badly made plugin if it throws an error when the selector contains no element. That's job #1 of any jQuery method, fail gracefully.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan lol I can't really say I can do any better. I just decided to use it since the effects looked fancy. Can you perhaps recommend some other modal plugins that are good aside for sweet modal?

Comment: I tend to just use Bootstraps' one. Easily extensible and modifiable.

Comment: I see. I just thought of trying something new for a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pages doesn't contain element with id #userPanel.
you can check if element exists before execute code:

```
if($('#userPanel').length) {
  $('#userPanel').iziModal({
    title: 'View User Data',
    subtitle: 'View and update each employee\'s records in the database',
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-user',
    padding: '15',
    fullscreen: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there like a way I can tell the script to run on that certain page where #userPanel exists only? I'm not that much of a pro with jquery

Comment: yes, just check if element exists, try the example above

Comment: Wow thanks! That worked just right. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Some jQuery plugins throw errors when called on an empty jQuery collection.

You should probably check if an element was found, before you call the modal on it:

```
if($('#userPanel').length) {
  $('#userPanel').iziModal({...})
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah this was the same answer the guy above mentioned. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using **class** name `userPanel` your code will be look this:

```
if($('.userPanel').length) { //<-- added condition for checking - begin
  $('.userPanel').iziModal({
    title: 'View User Data',
    subtitle: 'View and update each employee\'s records in the database',
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-user',
    padding: '15',
    fullscreen: true
  });
} //<-- added condition for checking - end
```

> The keyword is `if($('.userPanel').length) {` *your function goes here* `}`

Hopefully this code is usefull :-)